# How can i export message into text file.Only Selected User

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, xmppframework

Here is the code I got All Message But I want Only Selected message put into text File..

```
-(void)testMessageArchiving
{
    XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *storage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [storage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *messages = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    [self print:[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:messages]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question without knowing your CoreData architecture, but in general: you are requesting all messages.
You should make a NSFetchRequest that returns only the message you want to print.

Answer (score 0):

```
XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *storage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [storage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    NSError* error;
    NSString *predicateFrmt = @"bareJidStr == %@";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFrmt,[ _user valueForKey:@"jabberId"]];
request.predicate = predicate;


    NSArray *data = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```